# There was an error while processing your transaction: PPS: Timed out (2)

Tags: joomla, authorize.net, virtuemart

Did anyone experience this error "There was an error while processing your transaction: PPS: Timed out (2)" in joomla authorize.net payment method?
or did anyone have experience in integrating cardconnect to joomla authorize.net?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When does that happen?

Comment: In the final purchase in the cart. I'm using Cardconnect gateway by the way overriding authorize.net gateway. When I click "purchase", I was redirected to the payment method page with that error. What makes it confusing is, the credit card has been process the merchant center (with DECLINED transaction status) even the purchase failed. Any idea?